# Ajax function not working with jquery 2.1.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to fetch data with this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
    function getsections() {
        var a;
        try {
            a = new XMLHttpRequest;
        }
        catch(e) { 
            try { 
                a = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e) { 
                alert("your browser doesnot support ajax");
            }
        }

        a.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (a.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = a.responseText;
            }
        }

        var q = document.frm.category.value;
        var qs = "?q=" + q;
        a.open("GET", "get-section.php" + qs,true);
        a.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

It's working fine but when I use
`ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` then my ajax function stops working. Both functions are working fine separately but together AJAX function is not working.

Comment: jQuery doesn't make any changes to normal Javascript functions.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Ajax function i m using to fetch data on change trigger : Eg.(On select category from dropdown it shows related section in another dropdown) its working Fine. but when i add script src=“//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js” which is for another functions in the template my Ajax funcation stops working.

Comment: The problem is probably due to the other functions you added. Does it fail if you load jQuery without your other functions?

Comment: Separately both functions works fine. but together Ajax function of fecting sections stops working.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't show the code that's conflicting?

Comment: You have the wrong types of quotes in your `<script>` tag. It's supposed to be ASCII double quotes, you have curly quotes. Is it like that in the real page, or is that a copying error here?

Comment: <script src=“//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js”></script> <SCRIPT> function getsections(){
var a;  try{a = new XMLHttpRequest;}
catch(e){ try{ a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
catch(e){ alert("your browser doesnot support ajax");}}
a.onreadystatechange= function()
{if(a.readyState==4){document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=a.responseText;}}
var q=document.frm.category.value;    var qs="?q="+q;
a.open("GET","get-section.php"+qs,true);  a.send();
}</SCRIPT> when together second script does not work.

Comment: Please put the SECOND SCRIPT IN THE QUESTION!!!!

Comment: @Naeem It looks like you added the `<script>` tag to the question, why did you put the wrong type of quotes?

Comment: oh sorry my mistake, can i fix it or you already did? @Barmar